# Keyword in windows phone application submission

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

My app has been successfully published in the *Windows Phone App Store*. But my question is, when I was filling up my submission form like description, version, keywords, images etc. I had misspelled 2 keywords by mistakenly from 5 keywords.
I want to correct them. So if I'll go to update app, will that option show or not?
If it shows, then after I change my keyword will my app version change from `1.0.0.0` to `1.0.0.1` because I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No without changing the `Version` number you'll be able to update the same app.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj631569%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @BasantaMatia Were you able to update that way?

Comment: I have not updated till now. But I think it will not change my app version as there mentioned. I'll do after 2 days. Thanx again for the link.